# Deciding the controller action to which the data is submitted:-CakePHP

Tags: function, button, controller, cakephp-1.3

I am creating a form using Cake.In the form there is a 
    $this->Form->button("$i");
element. How do I specify to which function of the controller the data will be posted. If I am not wrong for accessing this data in the Controller,this form element needs to have a name. How do we specify the name for the button. I have been going through the documentation for a long time and dont seem to find any answers. Please advise me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button just submits the current form, that's not where you set the controller action. You do that in the `create` method of the FormHelper.

By default, forms are submitted to the action belonging to the current view that is served, but you can overrule that with the `action` option when creating your form. Like this:

```
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'edit'));
```

That would submit your form to the Users controller and the `edit` function within that controller.

Comment: Thanks for your post Oldskool.It really helped